# Syntax to update lookup columns with API rest in sharepoint 2016/online

Tags: lookup-column, update

I have a lookup column that I want to update using the Sharepoint REST API.
the column is called "Titular" and shows the title of a list of companies.
I have this code:

```
const body: string = JSON.stringify({Titular: {Title: "company1", Id: 1}});

 this.props.spHttpClient.post(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items(${this.state.idQ})`,
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
          {
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
              'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
              'odata-version': '',
              'IF-MATCH': '*',
              'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE'
            },
            body: body
          })
```

I do not know if the sintaxys is wrong but I have tried several options:

```
const body: string = JSON.stringify({"results":[{"Id":1,"Value":"company1"}]});
  const body: string = JSON.stringify( [ "1;#company1"]);
  const body: string = JSON.stringify( {_ObjectType_:"SP.FieldLookupValue",LookupId:1,LookupValue:"company1"});
  const body: string = JSON.stringify({ "__metadata": { "type": 'Collection(Edm.Int32)' },  "Results": [1]});
```

In all of them I get an error "400 (Bad Request)"

**Thank you! And regards**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the solution. Just put the lookup field id in this way

```
  const body: string = JSON.stringify({TitularId: 1});
```

change the name "Titular" by "TitularId" and add the id